# Auto-resize Guest Display and Seamless Mode grayed out DESPITE installing VirtualBoxAddition (Virtual Box 5.2.6, CentOS 7)

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBoxAddition and i still cant have resolution higher than 800x600 in full-screen mode. I did it in various ways

- Input , Insert Guest Addition CD, or by downloading iso and opening it from inside VM
- Then i tried typing in terminal either sudo ./VBoxAddition.run or sh ./VBoxAddition.run

There goes few lines, which last is "Starting Virtual Box Addition" and no errors. After rebooting CentOS, whole VM or even host computer i still cant enable 16:9 resolution by Auto-Resize. I also checked for logs in cd /var/log
There are few of them
- vboxadd-install.log
 - vboxadd-setup.log
- vboxadd-setup.log.1
- vboxadd-setup.log.2
- vboxadd-setup.log.3
- vboxadd-setup.log.4
- vboxadd-unintall.log

Inside them: (checked by nano  )

- vboxadd-install

  groupadd: group 'vboxadd' already exists
- vboxadd-setup.log 
  https://pastebin.com/YRXHCZUF
- vboxadd-setup.log.1

  Removing existing VirtualBox kernel modules.
- vboxadd-setup.log.2
  pastebin.com/jzkKyRqh
- vboxadd-setup.log.3
  Removing existing VirtualBox kernel modules.
- vboxadd-setup.log.4
  https://pastebin.com/8fFvDyGT

vboxadd-uninstall.log is empty.

Could anyone please help me, i dont know what to do to get full screen 16:9 resolution  on my computer in Centos & Virtual Box?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that installation has successfully passed. 
Ensure that you have `vboxadd-service.service` and `vboxadd.service` started:

```
systemctl -t service|grep vbox
```

If services started, then reboot your guest machine. During the boot, when `GRUB menu` will be showed, press `e` to edit boot menu entry. Find line with `linux16` (kernel parameters line) and put in the end `vga=ask`, then press `Ctrl+x` for boot. Therefore the linux kernel ask you to select appropriate graphical mode. If selected mode is convenient for you, save `vga=<your_choice>` to `/boot/grub2/grub.conf` for further boots.

Comment: Thank you a lot but i have few problems. After pressing e on boot screen and pasting vga=over, i could choose few resolutions but not one i need: 1366x768 of my laptop. Resolutions there are either too small or too big, some even makes system unable to boot. I tried editing grub.conf file with "vga=1366x768" but there was no file with this name (only grub.cfg). I wrote this line in grub.cfg and newly made grub.conf but it not helped me. Default resolution is still 4:3 800x600 with black boxes on sides of screen,

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk this could be a trick, but how to get auto-resize working?

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom resolution for the guest (e.g. for a 1440p display):

```bsh
$ vboxmanage setextradata "your vm" CustomVideoMode1 2560x1440x32
$ vboxmanage controlvm "your vm" setvideomodehint 2560 1440 32
```

Where `your vm` is the name from `Machine` > `Settings` > `General` > `Basic` > `Name` in VirtualBox Manager.